# An integral involving trigonometric and exponential function

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-numbers, exponential-function, trigonometric-integrals

Prove that $$ \int_{0}^{\infty}x^{2019}\sin(\sqrt{3}x)e^{-3x}\mathrm{d}x=\dfrac{2019!\sqrt{3}}{2^{2021}\cdot 3^{1010}} $$

Hence generalize the integral for any other value than $2019$.I know it can be done by considering the integral $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty} \sin(ax)e^{-bx}\mathrm{d}x=\dfrac{a}{a^2+b^2}$ and differentiating it again and again with respect to $b$, but it only works for smaller values, after some time calculation becomes very tedious.

Comment: Hint: use induction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

We integrate by parts $$\int_0^\infty x^ne^{wx}dx$$ where $w:=a+ib$ and $a<0$.

$$I_n:=\int_0^\infty x^ne^{wx}dx=\frac1w\left.x^ne^{wx}\right|_0^{\infty}-\frac nw\int_0^\infty x^{n-1}e^{wx}dx=-\frac nwI_{n-1}.$$

Then by induction,

$$I_n=(-1)^n\frac{n!}{w^n}I_0=(-1)^{n+1}\frac{n!}{w^{n+1}}I_0.$$

From this, taking the imaginary part,

$$\int_0^\infty x^n\sin(bx)e^{ax}dx=(-1)^{n+1}\frac{n!\sin\left((n+1)\arctan\dfrac ba\right)}{(a^2+b^2)^{(n+1)/2}}.$$

---

Here, $n=2019,a=-3,b=\sqrt3$.

Comment: Seems correct, maybe add a substitution of the original problem at the end for clarity

Comment: @razivo: I have turned the answer to a hint.

Comment: Very very big hint. Might have been better to just say how the complex exponential works.

Comment: @razivo: as you specified the complex-numbers tag, I imagined that you were familiar.

Comment: I’ve not noticed he specified it.

Comment: Yeah, I knew that it could be done by complex numbers, and that's also the reason i knew the answer for the case n=2019, but i couldnt solve it.Thanks for the help!

Comment: @razivo: ooops, sorry, you are not the OP. Complex exponentials are early notions in the study of complex numbers.